# AutoHotkey - Scrolling two PDF documents fit to page

Tags: pdf, autohotkey, scrolling

This answer kind of works from the previous posting using the notepad to scroll:   AutoHotkey - Scrolling two PDF documents.   If you have the document in fill the window and scroll continuously it works.  But when you have the two pdf files both on the show one page at a time, it skips pages (so it goes 1, 3, 5).  It sync skips, but still skips.  I want to be able to see the full page of both and scroll one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
Process, Priority, , High
SetWinDelay 0

; Replace "ThisClass" with the ahk_class of your PDF Viewer
GroupAdd, PDF_Group, ahk_class ThisClass

        return      ; end of auto-execute section

#IfWinActive, ahk_group PDF_Group

    PgDn::
    ; If the target window does not receive the keystrokes reliably, 
    ; try increasing the press duration via the second parameter of SetKeyDelay 
    ; as in these examples:
    ; SetKeyDelay, 10, 10
    ; SetKeyDelay, 0, 10
    ; SetKeyDelay, -1, 0
        Send {PgDn}
        GroupActivate PDF_Group  ; activate the next window of this group
        Send {PgDn}
    return

#IfWinActive


Esc:: ExitApp
```